# How does socket.io send messages across multiple servers?

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, socket.io

The [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) API has the ability to send messages to *all* clients.

With one server and all sockets in memory, I understand how that server one can send a message to all its clients, that's pretty obvious. But what about with multiple servers using [Redis](http://redis.io/) to store the sockets?

If I have client **a** connected to server **y** and client **b** connected to server **z** (and a Redis box for the store) and I do `socket.broadcast.emit` on one server, the client on the other server will receive this message. How?

How do the clients that are *actually connected* to the other server get that message?

- Is one server *telling the other server* to send a message to its connected client?
- Is the server establishing its own connection to the client to send that message?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Socket.io uses MemoryStore by default, so all the connected clients will be stored in memory making it impossible (well, not quiet but more on that later) to send and receive events from clients connected to a different socket.io server.

One way to make all the socket.io servers receive all the events is that all servers use redis's pub-sub. So, instead using socket.emit one can publish to redis.

```
redis_client = require('redis').createClient();
redis_client.publish('channelName', data);
```

And all the socket servers subscribe to that channel through redis and upon receiving a message emit it to clients connected to them.

```
redis_sub = require('redis').createClient();
redis_sub.subscribe('channelName', 'moreChannels');

redis_sub.on("message", function (channel, message) {        
    socket.emit(channel, message);
});
```

Complicated Stuff !! But wait, turns out you dont actually need this sort of code to achieve the goal. Socket.io has RedisStore which essentially does what the code above is supposed to do in a nicer way so that you can write Socket.io code as you would write for a single server and will still get propagated over to other socket.io server through redis.

To summarise socket.io sends messages across multiple servers by using redis as the channel instead of memory.

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this. More info [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167206/redis-pub-sub-or-socket-ios-broadcast). A good explanation of how pub/sub in Redis works is [here, in Redis' docs](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub). An explanation of how the paradigm works in general is [here, on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe).

Quoting the Redis docs:

> SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE and PUBLISH implement the Publish/Subscribe
>   messaging paradigm where (citing Wikipedia) senders (publishers) are
>   not programmed to send their messages to specific receivers
>   (subscribers). Rather, published messages are characterized into
>   channels, without knowledge of what (if any) subscribers there may be.
>   Subscribers express interest in one or more channels, and only receive
>   messages that are of interest, without knowledge of what (if any)
>   publishers there are. This decoupling of publishers and subscribers
>   can allow for greater scalability and a more dynamic network topology.

Comment: took me some time to decipher how this answered my question but after re-reading the docs with this info i realized what is happening behind the scenes is that socket.io is using redis pubsub to pub and sub messages for other server clients and its own