# Socket.io distribute across different servers

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I wanted to setup the socket.io server across 3 different machines. I have a load balancer setup for distributing the requests across the different servers, but how would I distribute the socket object that I get in the connection function in socket.io to the different servers? I know that we could use the RedisStore pub/sub for publishing and scribing to redis events, but suppose if I have a client A who has connected to machine 1 and if I have a client B connected to machine 3. How would client A send a message to client B? Or is there some other architecture in socket.io that I could use to achieve that?

Comment: You can't distribute a socket object to different servers.  A socket object belongs to a particular network card and can only be used with that network card.  You can have your servers communicate with one another in order to talk to a client that is connected to a different server.  It is common to use a single shared redis store for keeping track of which server a given client is connected to.

Comment: Thanks for that, are you aware if there is any other technology stack that allows us to do that?

Comment: You can read here: http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Comment: true, but that will setup different socket.io threads on the same box right?

Comment: The start of that article says: "If you plan to distribute the load of connections among different processes or machines".  Later on it refers to: "passing messages between processes or computers".

Comment: Yeah, I read that as well which was confusing, as I cannot find any other references to that in the rest of the document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70985/discussion-between-anonymous123-and-jfriend00).

Comment: More reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431662/how-does-socket-io-send-mess-messages-across-multiple-servers

Comment: More reading: http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/04/node-socketio-servicebus

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, a socket is a connection between two different machines (the client and the server in this case), so it can't be shared. For a basic structure to solve this problem, you'll need 3 components: the load balancer, the socket server, and a messaging system (Redis, RabbitMQ, etc.)

#### The Load Balancer

The outer most layer is the load balancer. Not all browsers support web sockets, so web socket libraries provide an HTTP polling failover. Essentially, a client initiates a handshake over HTTP, and the server tries to upgrade your connection to a bidirectional binary protocol built on top of straight TCP. If successful, you have a one-on-one connection with the server via web sockets. If it fails, the socket libraries will handle requests over HTTP with polling to simulate a web socket.

Thus, your load balancer must be configured to make sure that all of a client's requests go to the same server, or multiple servers could think that the client receives communication from them.

#### The Server and Redis

As expected, the server will handle all of the client connections and manage all communication to and from the client. However, when a client sends a message, the server will publish the message to Redis, and Redis will notify it's subscribers that a new message is available. On getting a message from Redis, each server will notify the appropriate clients.

If we were to step through your scenario, it might look something like this:

#### Resources

1. A load balancer
2. 3 socket servers (machines 1, 2, and 3)
3. Redis
4. Clients (clients A and B)

#### Steps

1. Client A requests a socket connection

   - Load balancer routes to machine 1 and will route all future requests there as well, if necessary
   - Socket server tries to upgrade client to a bidirectional socket
   - Server stores client with details
2. Client B requests a socket connection

   - Same as step 1, but connects with machine 3
3. Client A sends a message to client B

   - Client A sends a message to machine 1
   - Machine 1 publishes the message to Redis
   - Redis notifies subscribers of the new message, including Machine 3
   - Machine 3 notifies client B of the message

Of course, there are optimizations around not sending notifications to every single machine that would be useful at scale, but hopefully this is a good summary of what you'd need.